# Can I keep the same item for yanks in Emacs?

Tags: emacs

Something I do often in Emacs is to cut a bit of text, and then replace another bit with the cut text. So, say I've got the text I want to yank as the last item in my `kill-ring`. I yank it into the new place, then kill the text that was already there. But now the killed text is the latest item in the `kill-ring`. So next time I want to yank the first item, I have to do <kbd>C-y M-y</kbd>. Then the next time there are two more recent items in the `kill-ring`, so I have to do <kbd>C-y M-y M-y</kbd>, and so on.

I'm guessing there's a better way to do this. Can someone enlighten me please?

Comment: Not aware of any other way to do it. You might be able to save in a register but I've not used that myself.

Comment: You've hit upon a key problem with the kill-ring.  The most recently used item is most likely to reused.  So you don't want to order the ring chronologically.  Enter my LRU-yank package.  https://github.com/lewang/le_emacs_LRU_yank  I yank useful stuff with less keystrokes with it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should use `delete-region` instead of `kill-region`.

`delete-region` deletes the region without putting it in the kill ring. It is bind to `<menu-bar> <edit> <clear>` by default.

If you only want to use default bindings without using the menu, you could use `delete-rectangle` with <kbd>C-x</kbd> <kbd>r</kbd> <kbd>d</kbd> but it works on rectangle. It could be fine to use it on a single line like `delete-region`.

Comment: Thanks. I'm looking at a way to do it without having to do `M-x kill-region` each time, and I'd rather not add a new keybinding. Is there no way to do this with standard keybindings?

Comment: You could do a query-replace ( M-% ) by yanking in the minibuffer the thing you want to use to replace other things :   M-% thestringtoreplace RET C-y RET !

Comment: @Jérôme Yes, I think you're right. The only problem with that is that the replaced string must be the same each time, whereas I'd like to be able to manually replace a load of different things with the same string. I think this is one thing that's much easier to do with standard text editors (i.e. using Ctrl-C then Ctrl-V) than with Emacs.

Comment: I'll leave the question open for a day just in case, but mark this as completed if I don't get any other answers.

Comment: I added a word on delete-rectangle which could be used like delete-region on a single line, and delete-rectangle has a key binding by default.

Comment: Thanks - that's exactly what I wanted!

Comment: As for a default keybinding for `delete-region`, pressing Backspace over a selected region does `delete-region` instead of `kill-region` as of Emacs 24. See `delete-active-region`

Answer (score 10):

Several alternatives:

1. Turn on `delete-selection-mode`, and use <kbd>C-d</kbd> or <kbd>delete</kbd> to delete region without touching the kill-ring.
2. Use <kbd>C-x r s i</kbd> to save text to register i, and later, <kbd>C-x r i i</kbd> to insert the saved text.
3. If the pattern of texts to be replaced can be captured in a regular expression, use `query-replace-regexp` (<kbd>C-M-%</kbd>).

Comment: Nice - thanks. Is there ever a point where you can stop learning Emacs?!

Comment: In this scenario I use registers. They are often handy as you can have several of them !

Answer (score 4):

One of the oldest and best kept secrets in Emacs -- dunno why: Emacs has a ***secondary selection***.

And this is exactly what it is good for. It saves another selection of text for you to use, over and over.

Select some text, then yank the secondary in to replace it. Repeat elsewhere. Often this is more convenient, flexible, and precise than something like query-replace.

Please take a look, for your own good -- maybe it will stop being such a little-known feature...
http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/SecondarySelection

Answer (score 2):

I wrote this function to pop the newest item off the kill-ring:

```
(defun my-kill-ring-pop ()
  "Pop the last kill off the ring."
  (interactive)
  (when kill-ring
    (setq kill-ring (cdr kill-ring)))
  (when kill-ring-yank-pointer
    (setq kill-ring-yank-pointer kill-ring))
  (message "Last kill popped off kill-ring."))
```

So after I kill something I don't want to keep, I hit a key that calls this.

Comment: Thanks - that's a handy little thing to have.

Comment: What did you bind it to, out of curiosity?

Answer (score 0):

Related to this is `M-x browse-kill-ring`. If you use `M-x anything`, you can also use `M-x anything-show-kill-ring`.